# Does wallet support multi account/user?

Tags: bitcoinj

Does bitcoinj wallet support multiple accounts/users?

It seems `BIP44` is not supported and found multiple threads indicating lack of support. 
Just wanna get a definitely answer. **If not yet, any plan to support it in the near future?** 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoinj only supports one user and one account per wallet. Because i think managing multiple accounts can make the API
unnecessary complex. Normally you would use one wallet per user and that's what happens
automatically if you use your OS to switch users.

**Also**

I would recommend taking a look at [this](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/pull/1341) if you're interested in using BitcoinJ with BIP44. You would have to have one instance of Wallet per "BIP44 account" but it can still work.